# TypeError: unbound method "method name" must be called with "Class name" instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

Tags: python

I think this should be a simple question to answer.

I have the next classes:

```
class GruposHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.obtenerPagina()

    def obtenerPagina(self, pOpcion = None, pMensajeInformacion = None):
        opcion = pOpcion if pOpcion is not None else self.request.get('opcion') 
        usuario = obtenerUsuario()
        rsGrupos = obtenerGruposAll() 
        listaOtrosGrupos = []
        listaGruposSuscriptos = []
        blah blah ........

class NuevoGrupoHandler(webapp.RequestHandler): 
    def post(self):
        nombre = self.request.get('nombre')
        descripcion = self.request.get('descripcion')
        obj = Grupo.get_by_key_name(nombre)
        if obj:
            doRender(self, 'nuevo_grupo.html', {'mensaje_descripcion':'Ya existe un grupo con ese nombre.'})
        else:
            grupo = model.Grupo(key_name = nombre, nombre=nombre, descripcion = descripcion);
            grupo.put()
            grupoHandler = GruposHandler
            grupoHandler.obtenerPagina("gruposMios", 'Informacion: un nuevo grupo fue agregado.')
```

but it seems that method **obtenerPagina** from **GruposHandler** is not being called properly. This is the stacktrace I get:

```
TypeError: unbound method obtenerPagina() must be called with GruposHandler instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
grupoHandler = GruposHandler
```

==>

```
grupoHandler = GruposHandler()
```

---

UPDATE:

`GruposHandler.obtenerPagina()` method accepts 3 arguments:
`self`, `pOpcion=None` and `pMensajeInformacion=None`.

Since 2 of them are optional, you don't get:

```
TypeError: ... takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

when calling it like this:

```
GruposHandler.obtenerPagina("gruposMios", 'Informacion: ...')
```

Instead `GruposHandler.obtenerPagina()` interprets arguments like this:

```
self="gruposMios", pOpcion='Informacion: ...', pMensajeInformacion=None
```

and raises:

```
TypeError: ... must be called with instance (got str instance instead)
```

To get rid of the exception, you need to call this method from instance:

```
GruposHandler().obtenerPagina("gruposMios", 'Informacion: ...')
```

and `self` will be passed to `obtenerPagina` implicitly.