# Why the program only can run once.(PYTHON)

Tags: python, python-2.7, gstreamer

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import GObject #,Gtk
from gi.repository import Gst as gst
import datetime

def take_photo():        
    GObject.threads_init()
    gst.init(None)
    pipeline = gst.Pipeline()
    video_source = gst.ElementFactory.make('v4l2src', 'video_source')
    vconvert = gst.ElementFactory.make('videoconvert', 'vconvert')
    clock = gst.ElementFactory.make('clockoverlay', 'clock')
    timer= gst.ElementFactory.make('timeoverlay','timer')
    vrate = gst.ElementFactory.make('videorate', 'vrate')
    sconvert = gst.ElementFactory.make('videoconvert', 'sconvert')
    png = gst.ElementFactory.make('pngenc', 'png')
    multi_sink = gst.ElementFactory.make('multifilesink', 'multi_sink')
    caps = gst.caps_from_string("video/x-raw,format=RGB,width=800,height=600,framerate=5/1")
    timer.set_property('valignment','bottom')
    timer.set_property('halignment','right')
    clock.set_property('time-format','%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
    clock.set_property('valignment','bottom')
    caps1 = gst.caps_from_string("video/x-raw,framerate=1/1")
    png.set_property('snapshot',True)
    multi_sink.set_property('location','/home/pi/frame%05d.png')
    filter = gst.ElementFactory.make("capsfilter", "filter")
    filter.set_property("caps", caps)
    filter1 = gst.ElementFactory.make("capsfilter", "filter1")
    filter1.set_property("caps", caps1)
    pipeline.add(video_source)
    pipeline.add(vconvert)
    pipeline.add(timer)
    pipeline.add(clock)
    pipeline.add(filter)
    pipeline.add(vrate)
    pipeline.add(filter1)
    pipeline.add(sconvert)
    pipeline.add(png)
    pipeline.add(multi_sink)
    video_source.link(filter)
    filter.link(vconvert)
    vconvert.link(timer)
    timer.link(clock)
    clock.link(vrate)
    vrate.link(filter1)
    filter1.link(sconvert)
    sconvert.link(png)
    png.link(multi_sink)
    bus = pipeline.get_bus()

    pipeline.set_state(gst.State.PLAYING)
    print "Capture started"

    bus = pipeline.get_bus()#class

    msg = bus.timed_pop_filtered(gst.CLOCK_TIME_NONE,gst.MessageType.ERROR | gst.MessageType.EOS)
    print msg
    pipeline.set_state(gst.State.NULL)
```

Once the program run for the first time, it capture the image and when i run the second time, nothing happen. And i need to restart the whole python program in order to it to run again. Anybody can help me solve it?

Comment: I'm surprised it runs even once - you don't call the function `take_photo`, you only define it.  Where is `take_photo` called?

Comment: I thought i need to define take_photo function in order for it to import to other file. But is able to run but only one time. Do you have an idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
The code you posted is apparently not complete.

Comment: @renemilk, this is the completion of the program. I didnt left out any code.

Comment: That is very clearly not true, see @cdarke's comment.

Comment: @KevinKai:  how are you running this code?  From the command-line, an IDE like IDLE or PyCharm?  Is something in your project calling `take_photo`?  We need to determine where this function is called to be able to say why it is only running once - with the code you show it would not run at all.

Comment: Isn't def take_photo() is calling a function just by adding "def"? @cdarke

Comment: @cdarke I using shell to run the code and successfully capture the image with the code above only.  >>>  import xxx
>>> xxx.take_photo()
Capture started
<GstMessage at 0x737016c8>

Comment: well you need to define `__main__` methoda - at least - and call take photo from there..

Comment: @renemilk it seems its mcve because he calls this from shell, please dont downvote just because its poorly written.. the question makes sense

Answer (score 0):

What about implementing it as class, so do a proper initializationof  gstreamer stuff.. and in take_photo you just play the pipe and stop it afterwards.. in should be reusable then (from gstreamer point of view.. pipe can go to NULL and PLAYING over and over):

```
class TakePhoto:

    def __init__(self):
        GObject.threads_init()
        gst.init(None)
        self.pipeline = gst.Pipeline()
        .. do the element creation and their linking etc ..

    def take_photo(self): #this is reusable
        bus = self.pipeline.get_bus()
        self.pipeline.set_state(gst.State.PLAYING)
        print "Capture started"

        bus = self.pipeline.get_bus()#class

        msg = bus.timed_pop_filtered(gst.CLOCK_TIME_NONE,gst.MessageType.ERROR | gst.MessageType.EOS)
        print msg
        self.pipeline.set_state(gst.State.NULL)
```

Then python shell you can initialize one instance and call take_photo multiple times:

```
TakePhoto tp
tp.take_photo()
tp.take_photo()
```

This code is typed out of my head so I take no responsibility if it boils your HDD or anything.. and also I am not used to code in python.. so it may be full of bugs :D

but HTH

Comment: Hi, i having this error after i run your code on shell.  TypeError: unbound method take_photo() must be called with TakePhoto instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Comment: @KevinKai did you call it with instance tp or with TakePhoto (which is totally wrong)? check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245657/typeerror-unbound-method-method-name-must-be-called-with-class-name-instanc) for understanding the error..